# how to use abstract classes, and implementing them

Tags: java, class, oop, abstract

I'm not sure how eloquently I can really explain what I don't understand/need help with, I'm still Very new to Object Oriented Programming. This is regarding my coursework and I don't expect anyone to do it for me, I just need help understanding how to move on, and if I'm even on the right track.

Ok, so on to my question. Basically, I am attempting to create an arraylist which will hold a few objects which themselves has a bunch of information(obviously), my spec said to create an abstract class, which will be extended by my constructor class, which I did. The abstract class has a few variables (decided by spec) But I dont know how to move them over to my extended class.

I'll post my code below, and I hope it makes sense. I'd be very thankful for any help you all could provide. I'm very confused right now.

Basically, I would love to know, A) How do I create an object in my arraylist which will be able to contain everything in SportsClub and FootballClub, and preferably all the variables user inputted.

And B) I don't know how to print The object, When I print right now I get coursework.FootballClub@49233bdc, Which I'm sure there's a reason for but I need the information in the objects to display, E.g. name. And if possible to sort the results by alphabetical order with respect to name? I hope this is all written ok. Sorry and Thank you in advance.

```
   package coursework;
    import java.util.*;

    /**
     *
     * @author w1469384
     */
    public class PremierLeagueManager implements LeagueManager{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner c1 = new Scanner(System.in);
           Scanner c2 = new Scanner(System.in);
           ArrayList<FootballClub> PL = new ArrayList<FootballClub>();
           int choice;
           System.out.println("Enter 1; To create a club, 2; To Delete a Club, 3; To display all clubs and 99 to close the program");
           choice = c1.nextInt();
        //Creates and adds a new FootballClub Object

           while (choice != 99){
           if (choice == 1){
               System.out.println("Please Enter The games played for the club");
               int played = c1.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Please enter the number of wins");
               int wins = c1.nextInt();
               System.out.println("please enter the number of losses");
               int losses = c1.nextInt();
               System.out.println("please enter the number of draws");
               int draws = c1.nextInt();
               System.out.println("please enter the number of goals for");
               int goalsFor = c1.nextInt();
               System.out.println("please enter the number of goals against");
               int goalsAgainst = c1.nextInt();
               FootballClub club = new FootballClub(played, wins, losses, draws, goalsFor, goalsAgainst);
               PL.add(club);
               System.out.println("check");
           } 
        //Deletes a FootballClub Object
           if (choice == 2){

           }
        //Displays all Football Clubs in the PremierLeague array
           if (choice == 3){

               System.out.println(PL);
           }
        //Closes the Program  1

           choice = c1.nextInt();



        }
        }     
    }

    public abstract class SportsClub {
      public String name;
      public String location;
      public int capacity;


      public void setName(String Name){
          name = Name;
      }

      public void setLocation(String Location){
          location = Location;
      }

      public void setCapacity(int Capacity){
          capacity = Capacity;
      }

      public String getName(){
      return name;
    }

      public String getLocation(){
          return location;
      }

      public int getCapacity(){
          return capacity;
      }
    }

    public class FootballClub extends SportsClub {
        //Statistics for the club. 
        int played;
        int wins;
        int losses;
        int draws;
        int goalsFor;
        int goalsAgainst;

        public FootballClub(int gPlayed, int gWins, int gLosses, int gDraws, int gFor, int gAgainst){
            played = gPlayed;
            wins = gWins;
            losses = gLosses;
            draws = gDraws;
            goalsFor = gFor;
            goalsAgainst = gAgainst;
        }


    public void setPlayed(int newPlayed){
        played = newPlayed;
    }

    public void setWins(int newWins){
        wins = newWins;
    }

    public void setLosses(int newLosses){
        losses = newLosses;
    }

    public void setDraws(int newDraws){
        draws =  newDraws;
    }

    public void setGoalsFor(int newGoalsFor){
        goalsFor = newGoalsFor;
    }

    public void setGoalsAgainst(int newGoalsAgainst){
        goalsAgainst = newGoalsAgainst;
    }

    public int getPlayed(){
        return played;
    }

    public int getWins(){
        return wins;
    }

    public int getLosses(){
        return losses;
    }

    public int getDraws(){
        return draws;
    }

    public int getGoalsFor(){
        return goalsFor;
    }

    public int getGoalsAgainst(){
        return goalsAgainst;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FootballClub` inherits the variables declared in `SportsClub` so you can set them as you please.

```
public FootballClub(
    int gPlayed, int gWins, int gLosses, int gDraws, int gFor, int gAgainst,
    String inName, String inLocation, int inCapacity
) {
    played = gPlayed;
    wins = gWins;
    losses = gLosses;
    draws = gDraws;
    goalsFor = gFor;
    goalsAgainst = gAgainst;

    // set the variables from the superclass
    name = inName;
    location = inLocation;
    capacity = inCapacity;
}
```

`FootballClub` also inherits the methods declared in `SportsClub` so you can use the setters and getters too.

Normally you would create a constructor for `SportsClub` that sets these and then call that constructor from the `FootballClub` constructor.

```
// in SportsClub
protected SportsClub(
    String inName, String inLocation, int inCapacity
) {
    name = inName;
    location = inLocation;
    capacity = inCapacity;
}

// in FootballClub
public FootballClub(
    int gPlayed, int gWins, int gLosses, int gDraws, int gFor, int gAgainst,
    String inName, String inLocation, int inCapacity
) {
    super(inName, inLocation, inCapacity);

    played = gPlayed;
    wins = gWins;
    losses = gLosses;
    draws = gDraws;
    goalsFor = gFor;
    goalsAgainst = gAgainst;
}
```

You should also make your member variables [`protected` or `private`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) if you are using setters and getters.

> I don't know how to print The object

You need to override `toString`. There is a short tutorial [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/).

---

Also unrelated side note: all Java variable identifiers should start with a lowercase letter.

When you have a method like this:

```
public void setName(String Name) { name = Name; }
```

It should be:

```
public void setName(String inName) { name = inName; }
```

Or:

```
public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've been a great help!

And I know my syntax is terribad, thank you for helping me learn the proper way also.